# How to generate Javadoc HTML in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, javadoc

I wrote Javadoc style comments like this in my project

```
 /**Description..
 * @param ...
 * @return .....
```

How do I generate Javadoc HTML from Android Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Eclipse you can "Project -> Generate JavaDoc

In Android Studio you can "Tools -> Generate JavaDoc"

Comment: Hello, i do it but got the message "Error running Javadoc
           JDK path is not specified
           Cannot generate JavaDoc"